# Find out that user has finished move XAML-object in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my function I use:

```
if (e.IsInertial)
{
    e.Complete();
    [other code]
}
```

But if user moves object slowly, IsInertial == FALSE and [other code] doesnt run. Is there another way to find out when user has finished move object?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just want to use the other related events such as [ManipulationCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted.aspx).